# Вызов php функции в October CMS

Tags: php, cms, october

Здравствуйте.

Начал работать на October CMS, возник такой вопрос. В разделе code в partials,  как я понял, весь код обрабатывается либо до, либо после рендера всей страницы. А если прописать свою функцию, как ее правильно вызвать, например, по нажатию кнопки? Либо, как подключить внешний php файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, partials предназначены для статического использования. Функции там после рендера страницы перезаписывались и не распознавались. Код (в моем случае, это была отправка формы на почту) нужно писать в pages или layouts.